# Given $S, T$ subgroups of $G$, prove that $S\cup T$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if either $S\subset T$ or vice versa.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Quetsion: Let $S$ and $T$ be subgroups of a group $G$.
First, prove that if $S$ $\cup$ $T$ is a subgroup of $G$ then either $S$ or $T$ is a subset of the other. Then, prove that if either $S$ or $T$ is a subset of the other then $S$ $\cup$ $T$ is a subgroup of G.

My thoughts: Since I was given that $S$ and $T$ are subgroups of $G$ I know that they are closed, contain the identity and inverses. And therefore if $S$ and $T$ are subgroups of $G$ the shouldn't this also imply that $S$ $\cup$ $T$ is also subgroup of $G$? I'm not sure why $S$ and $T$ are subsets of each other and how to prove this fact

Comment: If $S \leq G$ and $T \leq G$ and $S \subset T$ then $S \cup T=T \leq G$

Comment: If there's something in $S$ but not in $T$ and there's something in $T$ but not in $S$, then where is the product of those two somethings?

Comment: Your title is not informative. Please make your titles specific, informative questions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $S$ is not contained in $T$ and $T$ is not contained in $S$, there exists $s\in S, t\in T$ $s$ is not in $T$ and $t$ is not in $S$, $st\in T\cup S$, if $st\in S$, $s^{-1}(st)=t\in S$, contradiction. If $st\in T, (st)t^{-1}=s\in T,$ contradiction.