# Show that $H\cup K$ is not a subgroup of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H=\{(1),(12)\}$ and $K=\{(1),(123),(132)\}$.

Both $H,K$ are subgroups of $S_3$
Show that $H\cup K$ is not a subgroup of $S_3$

IF $H, K$ are subgroups of $S_3$ then they must contain and identity and an inverse

How do I prove that for every $a \in H \cup K, a^{-1} \in H\cup K$?

Comment: To show $H\cup K$ is not a subgroup, find an element of $H$ and an element of $K$ whose product is not in $H\cup K$

Comment: the question in the title seems different from the question in the body

Comment: (12)(132), I get (12) which is not in $H \cup K$ so therefore it is not a subgroups. Does this sound good? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Did you make a typo.?  $(12)$ is in $H$

Comment: Yes, im sorry. That was suppose to be (13) @J.W.Tanner

Comment: That is correct, @cele

Comment: Thank you for your help @J.W.Tanner

Comment: To prove that if $a\in H\cup K$ then $a^{-1}\in H\cup K$, consider two cases: if $a\in H$ then $a^{-1}\in H\subseteq H\cup K$; if $a\in K$ the proof is similar. Why do you think that's going to help you prove that $H\cup K$ is not a subgroup?

Comment: @bof Sorry, I was writing my answer and did not see your comment.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958755/given-s-t-subgroups-of-g-prove-that-s-cup-t-is-a-subgroup-of-g-if-and?rq=1)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin No problem. That's what I get for posting an answer as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

$H$ is a subgroup of $S_3$; $(1)$ and $(12)$ are self-inverse.

$K$ is a subgroup too; $(123)^{-1}=(132).$

However, $H\cup K$ is not a subgroup,

because, if you compose $(12)\in H$ with an element of $K\setminus\{1\}$, you get a result not in $H\cup K$.

Answer (score 3):

One has $|H \cup K| = 4$. The order of every subgroup of $S_3$ divides $|S_3] = 6$. Thus $H \cup K$ is not a subgroup.